# Hive explode results in table

Tags: hive, hiveql

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code? If I run the select statement only, then its returning the results.

The code is working if I remove one of the line "location" or "stored as textfile".
Also please let me know if I can specify 'delimiter' too.

```
create table exploderesults 
location '/user/cloudera/sometest'
stored as textfile
as
select id,ph as phone, ct as city from explodetest
lateral view explode(phone)p as ph
lateral view explode(city)c as ct;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the two rows `stored as` and `location`. They have to be in a particular order according to the [manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable)

```
create table exploderesults 
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sometest'
as
select id,ph as phone, ct as city from explodetest
lateral view explode(phone)p as ph
lateral view explode(city)c as ct;
```

If you want to specify a delimiter,

```
create table exploderesults 
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sometest'
as
select id,ph as phone, ct as city from explodetest
lateral view explode(phone)p as ph
lateral view explode(city)c as ct;
```